# How do I draw the vertices of the following hollow polygon and connect them in the way I want?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks, polygons

[image]

What about polygons with a higher number of vertices?

Comment: `pts = CirclePoints[{1, \[Pi]/2}, 5]` would generate these  points. How is the connectivity defined?

Comment: I apologise for not being able to elaborate. In principle, draw the vertices of a regular polygon and connect arbitrary two vertices you choose to ensure that there are four edges coming out of each vertex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `StadiumShape` to draw the blank shape.

```
pts = CirclePoints[{1, π/2}, 5];
Graphics[{Thickness[.02], 
  Line[{{pts[[1]], pts[[2]], pts[[3]], pts[[4]], pts[[5]], 
     pts[[1]]}, {pts[[1]], pts[[4]]}, {pts[[2]], 
     pts[[4]]}}], {EdgeForm[{Thickness[.02]}], FaceForm[White], 
   StadiumShape[{pts[[1]], pts[[2]]}, .06], 
   StadiumShape[{pts[[3]], pts[[5]]}, .06]}, {Disk[#, .06] & /@ pts}}]
```

[image]

Add the `Text`.

```
pts = CirclePoints[{1, π/2}, 5];
Graphics[{Thickness[.02]
  , Line[{{pts[[1]], pts[[2]], pts[[3]], pts[[4]], pts[[5]], 
     pts[[1]]}, {pts[[1]], pts[[4]]}, {pts[[2]], pts[[4]]}}]
  , {EdgeForm[{Thickness[.02]}]
   , FaceForm[White]
   , StadiumShape[{pts[[1]], pts[[2]]}, .06]
   , StadiumShape[{pts[[3]], pts[[5]]}, .06]}
  , {Disk[#, .06] & /@ pts}
  , Text[Style[1, FontSize -> 40, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
   pts[[1]], {0, -2}]
  , Text[Style[2, FontSize -> 40, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
   pts[[2]], {3, 0}]
  , Text[Style[3, FontSize -> 40, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
   pts[[3]], {3, 0}]
  , Text[Style[4, FontSize -> 40, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
   pts[[4]], {-3, 0}]
  , Text[Style[5, FontSize -> 40, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
   pts[[5]], {-3, 0}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With CycleGraph and EdgeAdd:

```
hollowPolygon[n_, connect_ : {}, dlink_ : {}] :=
 Block[{edge, dedge},
  edge = UndirectedEdge @@@ connect;
  dedge = Alternatives @@ UndirectedEdge @@@ dlink; 
  Graph[EdgeAdd[
    CycleGraph[n, VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
     VertexCoordinates -> CirclePoints[{1, Pi/2}, n]], edge], 
   EdgeShapeFunction -> {dedge -> ({White, 
         StadiumShape[#, 0.06]} &)}, VertexSize -> 0.06 {1, 1}, 
   BaseStyle -> 
    Directive[Opacity[1], 
     EdgeForm[{Thickness[.015], Black, Opacity[1]}], Thickness[.015], 
     Black], VertexLabelStyle -> 15]
  ]

hollowPolygon[5, {{2, 4}, {1, 4}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 5}}]
```

[image]

```
hollowPolygon[7, {{2, 5}, {1, 5}, {3, 7}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 7}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

"What about polygons with a higher number of vertices?"

Using [`Graph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html) for a regular polygon

```
Manipulate[
 Graph[{
    UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[Range[n], 2, 1, {1, 1}],
    1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
    3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5} // Flatten,
  VertexLabels -> Automatic,
  VertexCoordinates ->
   RotateLeft[CirclePoints[n], Floor[n/2]],
  EdgeStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4]],
 {{n, 5}, Range[5, 10], ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]